# Is it possible to use Lightning Component/Aura inside Salesforce Mobile SDK Hybrid Local App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mobilesdk, aura, hybrid

We want to provide offline data support, but do the development using Lightning Component/Aura framework, So for this usecase I want to understand that is it possible to use Lightning Component/Aura inside Salesforce Mobile SDK Hybrid Local App and to bundle up our Lightning Component Code in the app itself

Comment: What did you do finally?

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage Lightning out feature to run the Lightning component code in your app. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_requirements.htm.

You can do oAuth authenticate the lightning-out code. 
But offline app load is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

Here’s a list of Lightning containers, what they are, and where you can use them as

Lightning Components: UI framework for developing dynamic web apps for mobile and desktop devices.
Environments:

Lightning Experience

Salesforce1 Mobile

Mobile SDK Hybrid Apps

Communities

Standalone Lightning Apps
Lightning Component Tabs – Create a Tab to display a Lightning Component
Environments:

Lightning Experience

Salesforce1 Mobile

Lightning Components For Visualforce – Integrate Lightning components into Visualforce pages for a dynamic development experience.
Environments:

Lightning Experience

Salesforce1 Mobile

Salesforce Classic

Mobile SDK Hybrid Apps

Communities

Lightning Apps – An App consisting of Lightning Components.
Environments:

Lightning Experience

Salesforce1 Mobile

Mobile SDK Hybrid Apps

External Sites

Lightning Out – Directly embed lightning components cross domain
Environments:

Mobile SDK Hybrid Apps

External Sites

Lightning Extensions – A mechanism for using custom-built components to replace existing components in the Salesforce1 Mobile App.
Environments:

Lightning Experience

Salesforce1 Mobile

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/46973)

Comment: @SebastianKessel This is one that should simply be downvoted. I agree it doesn't properly address or answer the question, but it's also not a comment. It's simply a very low quality answer that's a copy/paste from the docs. And the docs do say as quoted above that Lightning Containers can be used in `Mobile SDK Hybrid Apps ` which is the question that was asked.