# Lightning components inside Salesforce Mobile SDK

Tags: lightning, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, lightning-out

I am pretty new to mobile Development, so i have started with this [Trail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/mobile_sdk_hybrid?trail_id=mobile_sdk_intro) and created hybrid_remote app. Everything works great as i could able to access the data trough VF page.

Then I wanted to access the data through Lightning Components.So i have researched and understood that we can't directly use the Lightning Component(LC) inside SFDC mobile sdk, but we can leverage it from Lightning out as mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112433/is-it-possible-to-use-lightning-component-aura-inside-salesforce-mobile-sdk-hybr).

But the problem here is some how lightning component is not rendering anything on hybrid_remote app. But if i preview the same vf inside sfdc, i could able to see that lightning component has rendered. Please let me know what i am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

As of today Lighting Components are not supported in the Mobile SDK.  I have not heard about Lighting Components not rendering properly, the issues we have encountered have been about long term session management and navigation.  If your app is a simple, single page full screen web experience you may be able to simply wrap the LC in VF, though I wouldn't call it a great solution.  More info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm